# Extract multiple substrings from a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas Series` where I have to extract all the substrings within parenthesis. A string might contain multiple such substrings as well as no such substrings as well. How can such a condition be handled

```
abc(def)ghi(jkl)aaa
jklmnopqr(jkl)
(ab)cde(ghi)
lmnoprst uvwxyz
```

If I use `str.extract`, I can obtain only one substring at a time  from a string with `a.str.extract('.*\((.*)\)')`. So in effect, I miss the substring `def`.

How can this be solved.?

The desired outcome is

```
def
jkl
ab
ghi
```

Comment: Have you tried `str.extractall`? see [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)

Comment: @mr_mo I am getting asserion error `1 columns passed, passed data had 19 columns`

Comment: Please share code so I can help you debug.

Comment: @mr_mo- It was negligence from my side. I was using pandas 0.18. After updating to pandas 0.23 everything works fine as per the accepted answer below. Apologies from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df[0].str.extractall(r'\((\w+)\)')
```

Output:

```
           0
  match     
0 0      def
  1      jkl
1 0      jkl
2 0       ab
  1      ghi
```